# Getting error message "No javascript support found" instead of the response

Tags: javascript, java, json, browser, httprequest

When I try to make a request to [this website](http://www.biletix.com/solr/en/select/?start=0&rows=300&q=*:*&fq=start%3A%5B2018-04-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%20TO%202020-04-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%2B1DAY%5D&sort=score%20desc,start%20asc&&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=category&facet.field=venuecode&facet.field=region&facet.field=subcategory&facet.mincount=1&json.wrf=jQuery111304892331858278194_1522595307304&_=1522595307305) in a browser then I get a JSON text I need. And I want to make the same request in my Java program but I get an error message.

This is my java code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://www.biletix.com/solr/en/select/?start=0&rows=300&q=*:*&fq=start%3A%5B2018-04-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%20TO%202020-04-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%2B1DAY%5D&sort=score%20desc,start%20asc&&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=category&facet.field=venuecode&facet.field=region&facet.field=subcategory&facet.mincount=1&json.wrf=jQuery111304892331858278194_1522595307304&_=1522595307305";
        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        String returnedText = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(returnedText);
   }
```

When I run this program I expect to see the same result but instead I get this message:

```
<script>document.cookie = 'BXID=AAAAAAQESUmB+pCwyampPOjPp/TJoF5apqvu8IJ7uY9duhcYew==; path=/; domain=biletix.com';location.reload(true);</script><noscript>Javascript destegi bulunamadi. Lutfen javascript destegini aktiflestirin.</noscript>
```

In the <noscript> tag it basically says: "No Javascript support found. Please enable javascript support.".

How can I make this work and get the same result I get in browser?

Comment: A Java program isn't a browser. You have to take that response and inject it into a DOM Document properly for it to do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While making the request, just add a header Cookie with the value 'BXID=AAAAAAWcAVhLxgA1Bsrrqa1wtjASbH/dlp2o5J/5Bcx3RsFUew==; path=/; domain=biletix.com'

You should be fine

Comment: Thank you it worked when I add connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "'cookie_value'");